# Workflow for tagging a sprites with collision boxes

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, sprites, tools

I have some hundred of sprites and I need to mark collision boxes of them.

What kind of workflow can I use to help this proceed smoothly?

I've thought of using Tiled initially, however one of my requirements would be to not only mark multiple collision boxes per sprite but also to mark each one with a name or type category.

I would love to have final structure equivalent to:

```
<Bodies>
    <Body id="1">
        <CollisionBox>
            <Name>BODY_COLLISION</Name>
            <Vertices>
                <Vertex>12;13</Vertex>
                <Vertex>12;17</Vertex>
                <Vertex>11;17</Vertex>
            </Vertices>
        </CollisionBox>
        <CollisionBox>
            <Name>GROUND_DETECTOR</Name>
            <Vertices>
                <Vertex>12;11</Vertex>
                <Vertex>13;17</Vertex>
                <Vertex>14;17</Vertex>
            </Vertices>
        </CollisionBox>
    </Body>
</Bodies>
```

How can I build this data quickly & intuitively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that using Tiled editor was good enough. I imported actor sprites as tileset and annotated variuous object in each actor "tile", I gave those objects names and exported to tileset. Then from tileset one can easly get information that is wanted (every object on image is exported with x, y, width, height and name).